# Python using text file

Tags: python, text, python-3.x

I am using python33 and would like to take a string of numbers from a text file that contains words and numbers (line # 30 in the copy/pasted txt file below). After capturing the desired numbers, I would like to convert them using an equation (i.e. (number-30)/2) then find their average and write it to a new file (e.g. Scope22.txt or csv). I have many individual files this the first one that have to be similarly treated and each average would be written in the same file (Scope22.txt or csv). The attached file contains the numbers of concersn (0.0, 66.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.0, 64.0, 0.0, 76.0)....convert them ((number-30)/2) then find their average.
I sincerely appreciate your help.

my.txt:

```
MinorType Scope
ValidTime 201012132300
Range 536
Theta 48
ID SIT
Name SITE
LatCentre 23.45459
LonCentre -22.766379
Resolution1 1.0
Resolution1 1.0
Height1   11.0
Height3  600.0
Data index
InputFileType AAA,0,1,PPTOA
MinorProductParameters SCOPe,,BBBBBBB,KKKKK_LIST_SIT,0,0,1,1
TableLabels_Locations  ID Name Valid Lat Lon Range Theta BBN Yyy
TableStart_SiteLocations 
"LLL", "QQQQ_WWWWW", 1, 23.45459,-22.766379, 536.11,48.14, 55,22;
TableEnd_SiteLocations 
TableLabels_TableInfoSites  ID Lat Lon Range Theta BMHT PNTVlU Min Max Avg Median P95 AbsDev Var Sd Skew Curt
TableStart_TableInfoSites 
LLL, 23.45459,-22.766379,  536.11,48.14, -1.00,   0.00,  0.00, 81.00, 39.67, 64.00,  0.00, 35.26,1.44e+03, 37.96, -0.14, -2.13;
TableEnd_TableInfoSites 
TableLabels_TableDis Dis M
TableStart_TableDis 
LLL, 4,200,190,180,170,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,;
TableEnd_TableDis 
TableLabels_TableData Values_M
TableStart_TableData 
LLL,   0.0, 66.0, 70.0,  0.0,  0.0, 81.0, 64.0,  0.0, 76.0,;
TableEnd_TableData
```

here is my code:

```
STATS11_filename='C:/Python33/STATS11.txt'
STATS11_filename=open(STATS11_filename,'r')
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline() 
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline() 
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
line=STATS11_filename.readline()    
line=STATS11_filename.readline()
b=line=STATS11_filename.readline()
d=(str(b[7:-3]))
print(len(b[7:-3]))
STATS11_filename.close()
a=7
Scope22_filename='C:/Python33/Scope22.txt'
Scope22_filename=open(Scope22_filename,'w')
for i in range (len(b[7:-3])):
    if (b[a])>='64' or (b[a])<='254':
        Scope22_filename.write(b[a])       
             if a==53:
                 quit
             else:
                 a=a+2
Scope22_filename.close()
```

Comment: It seems you want us to write code for you. This is not how SO works. You post what *you* tried to do, and we help you spot the problems in it.

Comment: didn't mean too. I have added the code to the main question. I can print the numbers on screen but can't get them to be written in a file as I want them. I tried str with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable b being a string (b equals "0.0, 66.0, 70.0,  0.0,  0.0, 81.0, 64.0,  0.0, 76." in your exemple) and your variable a an int (a equals 7), then b[a] will refer to only one character, this can't be '64' (two character long).

I think what you were trying to do was to get a slice like so `if float(b[a:a+3])>=64 or float(b[a:a+3])<=254:`

(Which in Python can be improved by `if 64 <= float(b[a:a+3]) <= 254:`)

Are you actually trying to calculate the average of this series of number?

If so you should do something like:

```
b = list(map(lambda n: (float(n)-30)/2, b.split(","))
b = sum(b)/len(b)
```

Not related with your prob but instead of copy/past a bunch of `line=STATS11_filename.readline()` you can just do `[STATS11_filename.readline() for i in range(29)]` (even though i think there must be a function to jump to the line you want (maybe)).

**EDIT:** Indeed, you can just do that too: `b = STATS11_filename.readlines()[29]`.